# Attach BluePrism to PowerShell

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I'm trying to attach BluePrism to a PowerShell process and input some character.

[image]

Currently, I can launch PowerShell and get the PID by using C#, yet I'd like to actually attach the PowerShell process to BluePrism and I'm not sure how to do this use case.

I tried to use the `Application Modeller`(no C# code involved), but I can't get the process to attach or been launch. Furthermore, when I press the `Diagnostics` button, then `Take Snapshot(Now)`, I get a `Not Connected` message.

Comment: Powershell is easy to use using coding stages. consider developing "utility - powershell"!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you described above in not being able to attach to an open instance of Powershell using the configuration from your screenshot.

Using code made available on [this Blue Prism forum post](https://portal.blueprism.com/forums/general-discussion/general-discussion/unzip-folder-using-powershell), it appears that using a wildcard match for the window's title should work to attach to an open instance:

**Application Modeller**
[image: Application modeler configuration]

**Navigation (Attach) Stage**
[image: Navigation Attach stage configuration]

Comment: Esqew, can I ask why you fill out the inputs the same way you did in the application modeller? By identifying the Window title, process name etc. in the application modeller for the top-level element, here called Power Shell, you will automatically attach to an instance that has all these identifiers. No need to fill then out in the attach stage, unless you expect a difference in the inputs / parameters or when you need to provide the additional param "Child Index". Just wondering...

Comment: @Jarrick This was code that was provided on the Blue Prism Community Forums. Specifying these additional parameters ensures a level of granularity for a high confidence level that the automation will attach the correct application every time.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Utility - Environment. Start Process "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
2. Wait until PowerShell (Block + recovery + resume + retry?)
3. Navigate + Attach (only windows text = "Windows PowerShell")
4. Spy and send text, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to write a code for using powershell with BP, you can find the code to do that by using C#

```
PSConnector t = new PSConnector();
CustomResult r = new CustomResult();
    string command = Command;
    string argument = Argument;
    string member = Member;
    r=t.PSCExecuteSynchronously(command, argument, member);
    Result=r.Result;
    Status=r.Status;
    Exception=r.Exception;
```

Comment: What is that PSConnector? How to import that?